# Cant see the (Chainlink)requested data in my smartcontract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm trying to get data in my smartcontract, with is fetched from a Chainlink external adapter:

fetch bridge
"{"data":{"result":{"id":"UCAl9Ld79qaZxp9JzEOwd3aA","statistics":{"subscriberCount":"209000"}}},"jobRunId":"0x84aae6f7b7144fbc8196230158918797","statusCode":200}"

name: yutu

requestData: {"id": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), "data": { "chid": $(decode_cbor.chid)},"key": $(decode_cbor.key)}

parse jsonparse
"209000"

path: data,result,statistics,subscriberCount

data: $(fetch)

encode_data ethabiencode
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033068"

abi: (uint256 value)

data: { "value": $(parse) }

encode_tx ethabiencode
"0x4ab0d1902a02a37be17119894c2d9400f9bcf563bd4be47496af9a493a96eb412676916c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a76400000000000000000000000000002e495ea15b191aff2dea171abba537dc597d6f117642d37500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006571ad180000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033068"

abi: fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)

data: {"requestId": $(decode_log.requestId), "payment": $(decode_log.payment), "callbackAddress": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), "callbackFunctionId": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), "expiration": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), "data": $(encode_data)}

submit_tx ethtx
to: 0x34b33d85A6a642A6Eaa1fE554f576c6122FF64b6

data: $(encode_tx)

I'm trying to get the subscribercount in the below smartcontract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

/**

- THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES UN-AUDITED CODE.
- DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
  */

contract ConsumerContract is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

```
uint256 private constant ORACLE_PAYMENT = 1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY; // 1 * 10**18
uint256 public lastRetrievedSubscriberCount;

event RequestForSubscriberCountFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    uint256 indexed subscriberCount
);

/**
 *  Goerli
 * @dev LINK address in Sepholia network: 0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789
 * @dev Check https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/ for LINK address for the right network
 */
constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
    setChainlinkToken(0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789);
}

function requestSubscriberCount(
    address _oracle,
    string memory _jobId,
    string memory channelId,
    string memory apiKey
) public onlyOwner {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildOperatorRequest(
        stringToBytes32(_jobId),
        this.fulfillRequestInfo.selector
    );

    req.add("chid", channelId);
    req.add("key", apiKey);
    sendOperatorRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
}

function fulfillRequestInfo(bytes32 _requestId, string memory _info)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
{
    // Parse the JSON data to extract the subscriberCount
    (uint256 subscriberCount, ) = abi.decode(bytes(_info), (uint256, uint256));

    emit RequestForSubscriberCountFulfilled(_requestId, subscriberCount);
    lastRetrievedSubscriberCount = subscriberCount;
}

function getSubscriberCount() public view returns (uint256) {
    return lastRetrievedSubscriberCount;
}

/*
========= UTILITY FUNCTIONS ==========
*/

function contractBalances()
    public
    view
    returns (uint256 eth, uint256 link)
{
    eth = address(this).balance;

    LinkTokenInterface linkContract = LinkTokenInterface(
        chainlinkTokenAddress()
    );
    link = linkContract.balanceOf(address(this));
}

function getChainlinkToken() public view returns (address) {
    return chainlinkTokenAddress();
}

function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
    LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    require(
        link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
        "Unable to transfer Link"
    );
}

function withdrawBalance() public onlyOwner {
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
}

function cancelRequest(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    uint256 _payment,
    bytes4 _callbackFunctionId,
    uint256 _expiration
) public onlyOwner {
    cancelChainlinkRequest(
        _requestId,
        _payment,
        _callbackFunctionId,
        _expiration
    );
}

function stringToBytes32(string memory source)
    private
    pure
    returns (bytes32 result)
{
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
        return 0x0;
    }

    assembly {
        // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
        result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you point us to your request transaction, and the oracle address to which you are making it?

Based on context, I am assuming you are making a request against Chainlink's ETH Sepolia testnet oracle at 0x34b33d85a6a642a6eaa1fe554f576c6122ff64b6.

Based on the timing of your question, I am assuming that one of these failed oracle fulfill transactions is yours:

1. https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x7a440e81964e7552ba7784d7246fdd6b35b310f910c3639a8f88372e007640a4
2. https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x45862741e98669d733f6645f53b2078ab9359d9f0a46798ccab26d87ce6ba29a
3. https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xac2ce4aca4fbe7fff50234c3de568a4dbdaeea249a7e881d9f46152f4e93a7f5
4. https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xa50050fb9c77b40ebcb22dad25f095c4c9bdbd7ee22f52ffd2aa7f1e87c9d2ed

If you look at any of the above fulfill transactions, you'll see the contract execution error `Data versions must match`.

Looking at the Operator.sol (oracle) contract, here is the failed condition:
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol#L480

What version of `ChainlinkClient.sol` are you importing into your smart contract? I suggest you use the latest version to see if this makes a difference here.

Comment: This is my operator contract: 0x34b33d85A6a642A6Eaa1fE554f576c6122FF64b6

Comment: i import: import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure something is wrong with my way to encode the fetched data in the TOML job:

```
parse        [type=jsonparse path="data,result,statistics,subscriberCount" data="$(fetch)"]
        encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(bytes32 requestId,string info)" data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId),\\"info\\": $(parse) }"]
        encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                      abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                      data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"]
        submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0x34b33d85A6a642A6Eaa1fE554f576c6122FF64b6" data="$(encode_tx)"]
    
        decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
    """
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).